# Terminology of homocyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, terminology, cyclic-groups

This is a very quick question. Say we have $G= \underbrace{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \ldots \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}_{n}$. Is there a word for what the number $n$ is? Dimension is the word that comes to mind (That is, $G$ is the homocyclic group of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ of dimension $n$), but that doesn't seem to make sense in the context of groups

Comment: Well, as $G$ is also an $\mathbb{F}_p$ vector space, dimension makes sense

Comment: $G$ is the $n$-fold direct product of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, $n$ is also the rank of $G$ (the minimum number of generators). So "the homocyclic group of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ of rank $n$" would define the given group.